# Let $A_0 = 6, A_1 = 5, A_n = A_{n - 1} + A_{n - 2}$, for $n \ge 2$. There is (c,d) such that for sequence $A_n$. Find $c$ using the Fibonacci's.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let
\begin{align*}
A_0 &= 6 \\
A_1 &= 5 \\
A_n &= A_{n - 1} + A_{n - 2} \; \textrm{for} \; n \geq 2.
\end{align*}
There is a unique ordered pair $(c,d)$ such that $c\phi^n + d\widehat{\phi}^n$ is the closed form for sequence $A_n$.

Find $c$ using the Fibonacci and Lucas number sequences.

I'm stuck on how to start this. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a homework question from AoPS Intermediate Algebra. Here's a hint:

You should note that $A_0 = 2 F_0 + 3L_0$ and $A_1 = 2F_1 + 3L_1$. Claim that, in general,$$A_n = 2F_n + 3L_n.$$

Try to prove it by induction.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of the type $C r^n$ is a solution of $A_n = A_{n-1} + A_{n-2}$ iff $r^2 - r - 1 = 0$, i.e. iff $r =\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or $r = \hat{\phi} = -\frac{1}{\phi} = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ ($\phi$ is the so-called *golden number* or *golden ratio*); since the recurrence relation is linear, the most genereal solution of $A_n = A_{n-1} + A_{n-2}$ comes in the form:

$$\tag{*} A_n = C \phi^n + D \hat{\phi}^n$$

with constants $C,D \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, your solution (*) has to meet the initial conditions $A_0 = 6, A_1=5$ and this amounts to ask if there exist $C$ and $D$ such that:

$$\begin{cases} C + D = 6 \\ \phi C + \hat{\phi} D = 5\end{cases}\;.$$

Since the latter system of linear equations is Cramer’s, you find the unique solution:

$$C = \frac{6 \hat{\phi} - 5}{\hat{\phi} - \phi} = \frac{2 + 3\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}=:c$$

and:

$$D = \frac{5 - 6 \phi}{\hat{\phi} - \phi} = \frac{3\sqrt{5} - 2}{\sqrt{5}}=:d \;.$$